# Different product stock for sales channels in Shopware 6?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, e-commerce, shopware

Is it possible to have different stocks for a product for each sales channel?

As I know by default it is not possible. How can be such thing achieved?
Even if we use custom fields for each sales channel, how are these going to be connected to the stock?

Comment: You could use variants and show them only for selected sales channel

Comment: the products are with variants, I think that will not work

Answer (score 1):

I implemented something like that as a custom entity (with one-to-one relation with Product visibility). Extended product detail page in administration with a new tab to manage it.

After that i overrided `Shopware\Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\SalesChannelProductDefinition`

in my plugin to change `processCriteria` method to change the availability filter, as i also need active flag per sales channel.

Answer (score -1):

I found a plugin which could be somehow alternative:
https://store.shopware.com/en/dvsn964775483854/store-stocks-per-subshop-multiple-warehouses.html

I think it could be used as a base concept feature for saleschannels too.

Context:
Inside description of plugin you can find:

> Store stocks per sales channel (several warehouses) With this plugin
> you can map multiple warehouses and maintain multiple stocks (per
> warehouse) for your products. You can then assign any warehouse to
> each sales channel so that different sales channels can access
> different warehouses and stocks.

why it solves the problem?

- Because you can assign warehouse to saleschannel

How it solves the problem?

- Creates one warehouse per saleschannel
- While changing stock of product inside warehouse you are changing the stock inside specific saleschannel

Shows how to use the tool/library?

> In the administration of the products you will find a list of all additional warehouses in the "General" tab below the "Availability". Here, however, you can assign a separate stock per warehouse to each product. The "available stock" within each warehouse is automatically calculated according to Shopware standard. When an order is placed within a sales channel, only the stock of the assigned warehouse is reduced.